# ddply to compress text data on a data.frame in R, in relation to a single column

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

i have a data frame called df, with this structure:

```
 X C D E F
 A b c d e 
 A f g h i
 B l m n o
 B p q r s
```

I want to obtain a result like this:

```
 X   C    D    E    F
 A  b f  c g  d h  e i
 B  l p  m q  n r  s o
```

i could use ddply, just like this:
test <- ddply(df, "X", ...)

I don't know how to complete it.

Could you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: If your variables are characters then simply `aggregate(. ~ X, df, toString)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'X', use `summarise_all` to `paste` the elements in each group column wise

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(X) %>%
   summarise_all(funs(paste(., collapse=' ')))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#      X     C     D     E     F
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     A   b f   c g   d h   e i
#2     B   l p   m q   n r   o s
```

---

If we wanted a `list` then

```
df %>%
    group_by(X) %>% 
    summarise_all(list)
```